# each a div using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I implemeted an ajax method that returns a products list, i want to display those products in a div, that means i have this div that i want to repeat depending on the number of products and display in the p tag the name of the product, i tried this code but it didn't work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.get("./products", function(data) {
    $('#product').each(function () {
      $(this).find("p").each(function() {
        $("#productName").append(data.nameEn);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

All the contents of this div i want to repeat

```
<div id="product" class="col-md-55">
 <div class="thumbnail">
   <div class="image view view-first">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"> 
       <img style="width: 100%; display: block;" alt="image" />
     </a>
     <div class="mask">
       <p id="productName">...</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to clone the `#product` div for every item store in the `data` returned form your AJAX request?

Comment: Does the ajax get function work with the ./products string? How about the value returned. Is it in json string or a js object?

Comment: You don't do a foreach on the data

Comment: An `id` should be unique throughout the whole DOM and should not be repeated. I mention this because I see you're doing `$('#product').each(function () {});`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes that's what i mean

Comment: @LookForAngular the Ajax method returns list of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to clone an instance of the `#product` div for each entry in the returned data you would instead need to loop through the data set and append a new clone of the element. To do that would look something like the below. Note the change of `id` to `class` on `productName`:

```js
$.get("./products", function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    var $clone = $('#product').clone().removeAttr('id');
    $clone.find('.productName').text(item.nameEn);
    $clone.find('img').prop('src', item.imageUrl); // amend this property name to match the object
    $clone.appendTo('#your-containing-element');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="product" class="col-md-55">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image view view-first">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
        <img style="width: 100%; display: block;" alt="image" />
      </a>
      <div class="mask">
        <p class="productName"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can explain this line to me : $clone.appendTo('#your-containing-element');

Comment: That line appends the clone you made of `#product` to an element you would need to add to the DOM which contains all the new cloned divs.

Comment: how can i delete the first div. because when i cloned the #product div and i displayed the name of the products, the name of the first div is empty

Comment: You don't necessarily need to remove it, you can just hide it with `#product { display: none; }` in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

You should do the loop into the json itens and create a div for each element inside the array, look this working example:

```js
//native JS for get the JSON
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

//you change this part for your json
getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', function (err, data){createDivs(err, data);});

function createDivs(err, data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#items").append('<div id="'+ data[i].id +'" class="itemClass">"'+  data[i].title +'"</div> <div class="rectangle" style="background-image:  url('+data[i].url+');"></div><br>');
    
    //just break after 10
    if(i == 10){
    break;
    }
    }
    
    }
```

```css
.itemClass{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background:grey;
    color:white;
}

.rectangle{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in this case is make a "template" - a copy of the div but hidden. Then in the callback, I `clone` the template as many times as I need, fix the productName, and insert it into the DOM with `before` or `after` and remove the hidden attribute/class. But you can't use `#productName` because ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the `id` and place it in the class and the iterate through each product. Something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="product col-md-55">
 <div class="thumbnail">
   <div class="image view view-first">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"> 
       <img style="width: 100%; display: block;" alt="image" />
     </a>
     <div class="mask">
       <p id="productName">blah</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.product').each(function () {
   $(this).find("p").each(function() {
     // Do what ever you want with the content inside the `<p>` tag using $(this).html().
     alert($(this).html());
   });
 });
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/a2nbgere/